# Controlling digits in R in write.csv

Tags: r, csv

I want to write a data frame into csv which contains numeric columns as well as character columns.

Some numeric columns are integers which I want to display as integers and some are decimals in which I need to control the number of digits after decimal and obviously no change in character columns

How can I do this?
Eq a particular row in that dataframe is

```
XYZ  8200  0.306060606 ABC
```

Output should be

```
XYZ 8200 0.30 ABC
```

Regards

Comment: Do you want to round the decimals? (e.g. `0.31` is closer to `0.306060606` than `0.30`)

Comment: Not required. But even if it happens its OK. My greater concern is truncation

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to control number of decimal digits in write.table() output?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14260646/how-to-control-number-of-decimal-digits-in-write-table-output)

Comment: I saw that answer. I tried using format(), but I am not getting the required output

Comment: See [how to make a great R reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).  This works for me:  `test <- data.frame("XYZ", 8200, 0.306060606, "ABC"); format(test, digits=2)`

Comment: Try this one and see what happens 
xyz <- data.frame(8200,365.2121,0.3060);format(xyz,digits=2)

Comment: @Frank I am extremely sorry for my bad formatting. Will reiterate the comment. I tried the following thing and it did not work `xyz <- data.frame(8200,365.2121,0.3060);format(xyz,digits=2)` The reason is 365.2121 is converted to 365

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will force two digits after the decimal place:

```
# read in some sample data
xyz <- data.frame(v1 = c("a", "b"), 
                  v2 = c(8200, 8100), 
                  v3 = c(365.2121, 365.2122), 
                  v4 = c(0.3060, 0.3260))

format(xyz, digits=2, nsmall=2)
#  v1      v2     v3   v4
#1  a 8200.00 365.21 0.31
#2  b 8100.00 365.21 0.33
```

If you don't want columns with whole numbers to also have those decimal places (e.g. column `v2` in this example), you could do something like splitting `xyz` into columns that need to be formatted and other columns:

```
numbs2format <- 
    xyz[, (sapply(xyz, function(x) isTRUE(sum(x %% 1) > 0)))]
# ignore the warnings from trying to use %% on non-numerics
other.columns <- 
    xyz[, (sapply(xyz, function(x) !isTRUE(sum(x %% 1) > 0)))]

cbind(other.columns, format(numbs2format, digits=2, nsmall=2))
#  v1   v2     v3   v4
#1  a 8200 365.21 0.31
#2  b 8100 365.21 0.33
```

Comment: Hello, but then integer 8200 is displayed as 8200.00 which I dont want

Comment: Hello, This is right but I could have used `as.integer()` as well to maintain the integer columns the way they are. I was searching for an answer within `write.csv()` whether it is directly available or not. That is, am I missing something. Data Modification was always an option open

Comment: However I would still upvote this solution as to be more generic than `as.integer()`

Comment: @QuantLearner So far as I know, there is no argument to `write.csv` that would allow you to achieve such a thing.  So I answered with how to feed `write.csv` something in the appropriate format.  If you have an approach you prefer using `as.integer`, feel free to post it as an answer, and even accept it if you want.