# How to specify the number of decimal places for numeric values written to a file in R?

Tags: r

I want to take this data frame

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = c(1.224, 1.3), col2 = c(0.8011, 1.90))
```

and write it to a file so that each numeric value displays exactly two decimal places.  I tried the solution given in [Controlling digits in R in write.csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30283454/controlling-digits-in-r-in-write-csv), but when I use

```
write.csv(format(df, digits = 2, nsmall = 2), "./testout.csv")
```

the numeric values in my file have been converted to strings.  So I tried the solution given in [Formatting Decimal places in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3443687/formatting-decimal-places-in-r), as follows:

```
write.csv(format(round(df, 2), nsmall = 2), "./testout.csv")
```

but, again, the file shows that my numeric values have been converted to strings.

How can I write this data.frame to a file so that the numeric values are written as numeric values with exactly two decimal places?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `quote=FALSE` to your `write.csv` call.

For example:

```
df[] <- lapply(df, sprintf, fmt='%.02f')
write.csv(df, f <- tempfile(), row.names=FALSE, quote=FALSE)
file.show(f)
```