# Controlling number of decimal places in write.table while maintaining class "numeric"

Tags: r, write.table

Generally speaking, controlling the number of digits to display when calling  `write.table` is straightforward. Given the excellent question and answer seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14260646/4408538), we see that `format` is the means to accomplish this feat. However, this creates a file that when viewed by a text editor, shows quotes around numeric values. This can be turned off by setting `quote = FALSE` in `write.table`. Unfortunately, this has the side effect of not putting quotations around `character` columns. Observe:

**Normal Case (without format and standard output behavior)**

```
df <- data.frame(c1 = 1:5/100, c2 = LETTERS[1:5])
write.table(df, file = "test.txt", sep = "|")

## when you open test.txt in a text editor, the middle column correctly 
## appears as a numeric (i.e. no quotes), however there are only 2 decimals displayed.
## It should also be noted that the quotes are present in c2 (this is what we want).
    "c1"|"c2"
"1"|0.01|"A"
"2"|0.02|"B"
"3"|0.03|"C"
"4"|0.04|"D"
"5"|0.05|"E"
```

**With Format**

```
df$c1 <- format(df$c1, digits = 4, nsmall = 4)
write.table(df, file = "test.txt", sep = "|")

## when you open test.txt in a text editor, the middle column correctly 
## displays four decimal places, however it now appears to be a character
## (i.e. with quotes). Again, it should be noted that the quotes are 
## present in c2 (again, this is what we want).
     "c1"   |"c2"
"1"|"0.0100"|"A"
"2"|"0.0200"|"B"
"3"|"0.0300"|"C"
"4"|"0.0400"|"D"
"5"|"0.0500"|"E"
```

**With Quotes=FALSE**

```
write.table(df, file = "test.txt", sep = "|", quote = FALSE)

## when you open test.txt in a text editor, the middle column correctly 
## displays four decimal places with no quotes. However the quotes on column
## c2 (and everywhere else) have been dropped (this is NOT what we want).
    c1  |c2
1|0.0100|A
2|0.0200|B
3|0.0300|C
4|0.0400|D
5|0.0500|E
```

## Question

Is there a way to write a data frame to a file that controls the number of decimal places while maintaining the standard instructions of `write.table` for displaying quotes (i.e. no quotes around numeric fields and quotes around character fields)? Here is my desired output:

```
     "c1" |"c2"
"1"|0.0100|"A"
"2"|0.0200|"B"
"3"|0.0300|"C"
"4"|0.0400|"D"
"5"|0.0500|"E"
```

Comment: Would it help to use `round()` before writing the table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quote argument in `write.table` supports numeric vectors to specify the location of the columns to add quotes, so

```
write.table(df, file = "test.txt", sep = "|", quote = 2)
```

works for this example, producing

```
"c1"|"c2"
"1"|0.01|"A"
"2"|0.02|"B"
"3"|0.03|"C"
"4"|0.04|"D"
"5"|0.05|"E"
```